# Executing compiled C file in Linux terminal : understanding syntax (buffer overflow application)

Tags: c, terminal, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to learn the buffer overflow functionality, and I found:

```
ouah@weed:~$ ./vuln1 `perl -e 'print "A"x300'`
```

where vuln1 is the compiled C file vuln1.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>

main (int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
   char buffer[256];
   if (argc > 1)
      strcpy(buffer,argv[1]);
}
```

So I would know the signification of those weird ``perl -e 'print "A"x300'`: what do the "perl -e" and the "print" are supposed to mean here (I know that there are supposed to be the main() arguments), and same for "A"x300 that looks like a multiplication but less '*' (because the goal of this command is to overflow buffer) and in the same time to hexadecimal writing...

Comment: I'm no perl expert, but I'm pretty sure it just generates 300 `A` characters. More than enough to overflow the buffer.

Comment: So your question is about pearl rather then about C?

Comment: What do you get when you run `perl -e 'print "A" x 300'`?  You should see 300 upper-case letters A.  So, the shell runs `perl` and passes a string of 300 letters to the program as `argv[1]` (`argv[0]` is the name of the executable, `./vuln1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl is [a scripting language](https://www.perl.org/). `perl` with the `-e` switch evaluates the next argument as code directly (instead of running a script file).

`print` is a [Perl built-in function that outputs its arguments](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print).

`x` is the [repetition operator in Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Multiplicative-Operators). `"A" x 3` yields `"AAA"`.

The final piece of the puzzle is that backticks (`` ` ` ``) in bash will execute their contents as command and yield whatever that command printed to stdout.

So, this is a quick and easy way to generate 300 `A`'s as argument to `./vuln1` which will overflow the 256-byte buffer when the argument is read.

Replace `./vuln1` with plain `echo` to see what argument gets eventually passed.

Comment: Okkk ! That's clear now, sorry to put the topic in C channel, I didn't get that perl was language.

Comment: It's a mix of Perl and shell language.